# ¿Cómo pasar un arraylist como atributo de un objeto?

Tags: java, java-8

Un conjunto de objetos de la clase Profesor(nombre,apellido,curso), los tengo que añadir como atributos de una clase Departamento(edificio, profesor, escuela)

```
    Profesor profesor1 = new Profesor("JULIAN","GUTIERREZ LOPEZ","78542141F","MATEMÁTICAS");
    Profesor profesor2 = new Profesor("FRAN","FELIPE LOPEZ","78785141L","MATEMÁTICAS");
    Profesor profesor3 = new Profesor("ELENA","PINDADO SANCHEZ","58445142N","CIENCIAS");
    Profesor profesor4 = new Profesor("LUCÍA","HERNÁNDEZ HERRERO","88375349K","CIENCIAS");
    Profesor profesor5 = new Profesor("PABLO","LOPEZ LOPEZ","78544241P","QUÍMICA");
    Profesor profesor6 = new Profesor("LUCAS","JIMENEZ RODRIGUEZ","77825141L","QUÍMICA");
    Profesor profesor7 = new Profesor("MARIA","PINDADO SAEZ","58447852E","FÍSICA");
    Profesor profesor8 = new Profesor("ANDREA","FERNANDEZ MARTIN","87725349M","FÍSICA");
    Profesor profesor9 = new Profesor("IGNACIO","FELIPE GONZALEZ","78211351H","INFORMÁTICA");
    Profesor profesor10 = new Profesor("MARIANO","JIMENEZ IZABARRA","78515781L","INFORMÁTICA");
    Profesor profesor11 = new Profesor("VANESA","SAN JUAN PÉREZ","55896242I","INFORMÁTICA");
    Profesor profesor12 = new Profesor("LIDIA","DE LUCAS GUTIÉRREZ","75143749N","INFORMÁTICA");

    ArrayList<Profesor> ProfesoresMates = new ArrayList<Profesor>  ();
    ProfesoresMates.add(profesor1);
    ProfesoresMates.add(profesor2);
    ProfesoresMates.add(profesor3);
    ProfesoresMates.add(profesor4);

    //Crear 3 departamentos

    Departamento dep1 = new Departamento(ProfesoresMates,"MATEMÁTICAS Y CIENCIAS", "EDIFICIO 4B");


//CONSTRUCTOR DE CLASE DEPARTAMENTO

public class Departamento {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public Profesor profesores;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String nombre;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String edificio;

    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public Departamento(Profesor profesores, String nombre, String edificio) {
        this.profesores = profesores;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edificio = edificio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Osea lo que entiendo, es que a la clase Departamento le quieres pasar por parametro un ArrayList con los profesores?

Comment: hola @Juan, idealmente haz una mejor explicación de tu problema y qué es lo que ya tienes.
no queda del todo claro que es lo que no entiendes

Comment: Exacto, pasar un Arraylist como atributo

Comment: Un ArrayList es exactamente igual que cualquier otra clase de objeto. Por eso nos cuesta entender porqué te tendría qué problemas te está causando. ¿Puedes poner el código de lo que pruebas?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para pasar un ArrayList como atributo en este caso, es igual que pasar otros parametros con sus tipos.

Por ejemplo tenemos la clase Profesor.

```
public class Profesor {

  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;
  private String curso;

  public Profesor(String nombre, String apellido, String curso) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.curso = curso;

  }

  public String getNombre() {
      return this.nombre;
  }


}
```

Vemos que esta clase recibe un nombre, apellido y curso, y ademas tiene un metodo que nos devuelve el nombre del profesor.

Si quieremos guardar en nuestra clase departameto, los profes que pertenecen al dicho departamento, simplemente le pasaremos un ArrayList de profesores por el constructor o de otro modo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Departamento {

  private String edificio;
  private ArrayList<Profesor> profesores;
  private String escuela;

  public Departamento(String edificio, ArrayList<Profesor> profesores, String escuela){
    this.edificio = edificio;
    this.profesores = profesores;
    this.escuela = escuela;
  }


  public ArrayList<Profesor> getProfesores() {
      return this.profesores;
  }

}
```

Fijate que hay un metodo llamado **getProfesores** que nos devuelve todos los profesores de ese departamento.

Ahora la pregunta como muestro todos los profesores? Bien simplemente tenemos que recorrer el arraylist que nos devuelve ese metodo(getProfesores) y listo.

MAIN

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Profesor> profesores = new ArrayList<>();

   //Creamos unos cuantos profesores
   Profesor profe1 = new Profesor("profe1", "profe1", "m1");
   Profesor profe2 = new Profesor("profe2", "profe2", "m2");
   Profesor profe3 = new Profesor("profe3", "profe3", "m3");

    //Guardamos los dichos profesores
   profesores.add(profe1);
   profesores.add(profe2);
   profesores.add(profe3);

  //Creamos el departamento con los parametros y el ArrayList con los profesores
  Departamento departamento = new Departamento("edificio", profesores, "escuela");

  //Simplemente recorremos los elementos, y mostramos el nombre de cada profesor
  for (Profesor object: departamento.getProfesores()) {
      System.out.println(object.getNombre());
  }
  }
}
```

[Aquí](https://repl.it/repls/MellowHorribleViruses) por si quieres probarlo.

Espero haberte ayudado y cualquer duda comentala.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias! A la hora de hacer el for me sale un error, me dice que el método getProfesores debe ser static. Como se arregla

Comment: Fijate si esta bien el codigo, acabo de compilar lo que escribio Eugeni Bejan y no me da ningun error el for, saludos.

Comment: Así es, mira bien como estas intentando llamar al método. En cualquier caso se ha resuelto la duda sobre como pasar parámetros?